# Delete all occurences of any word matching a partial string in sed

Tags: sed, string-manipulation

Assume that I have the following line:

```
group blue:green yellow green redtomblue black !greyTOMwhilte !purple redblue
```

I need to delete from it all words that contain the string "tom" or "TOM" using sed.

I have managed to get this far:

```
sed 's/^ *\(.*\)[!]*[A-Za-z0-9_]*[tT]\{1\}[oO]\{1\}[mM]\{1\}[A-Za-z0-9_]*\(.*\)/\1 \2/g'
```

But this only deletes the *last* occurrence, not all of them. Using my example above the result is:

```
group blue:green yellow green redtomblue black !grey  !purple redblue
```

How can I use `sed` to remove any word containing either of the specific substrings "tom" or "TOM"?

Answer (score 3):

What about this one?

```
sed 's/\S*\(tom\|TOM\)\S*//g'
```

resp. in non-GNU versions of `sed` this should work:

```
sed 's/[a-zA-Z0-9_!]*[Tt][Oo][Mm][a-zA-Z0-9_!]*//g'
```

This will substitute all *words* (i.e. strings beginning with 0 or more non-whitespace characters (`\S`) followed by `tom` or `TOM` and again 0 or more non-whitespace characters) with an empty string.
Probably you should also remove double spaces:

```
sed 's/\S*\(tom\|TOM\)\S*//g;s/\(\s\)\s*/\1/g'
```

Comment: @Sims: I added another version which should work with `non-GNU` sed versions.